# Problem with cast on the function prepareForSegue

Tags: swift, casting, segue

I have an error with my segue. When I click on the information button the application crashes. In the title View I have multiple segues. The first one is for send array to the register view and the others is for opening my information Pop Up.

The message error is:

[image: showing error message]

And this is the main StoryBoard:

[image: main Storyboard]

How do I fix this?

Comment: it's better to post code & crash as text

Comment: I take note of your remark for the next time. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have 2 segues then you need to differentiate them with the identifier

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
   if segue.identifer == "toPopUp" {
      if let yourVC = segue.destination as? YourPopController {
        // set data
      }
   }
   else {
      if let yourVC = segue.destination as? RegisterViewController {
         // set data
      }
   } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, despite my research I did not know it was possible to differentiate the segues. Thanks to you, it'll help me move forward in my code